# DEV-C++ 5.11 debugging issue with STL iterator

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, dev-c++

I am using DEV-C++ 5.11 on Windows 10. I find that the Debugger support for STL containers seems not very good, or maybe I am missing something. I have following code:
xxx.h

```
typedef std::vector<double> vd;
typedef vd::const_iterator it_vd;
```

xxx.cpp

```
vd vec;
......
for (it_vd it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++ it)
{
    std::cout << "element " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

First, I found that I cannot see the content of vec by using the watch. Second, if I put the breakpoint at the line in the for loop, once the debugger goes there, it cannot get out, no matter I use next line/next instruction or continue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Dev-C++'s debugger is notoriously bad, even non-existent. Any time I tried to use it, it simply did not work. I recommend switching to Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. It is completely free and comparable to the Professional versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Use "\n" (for new line) instead of endl.**

Comment: Please explain how that fixes the debugger issue.